# How do you enable "Dynamic Content" for the Start Page?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

On the Start Page for Visual Studio 2013, there is a section entitled "Announcements".

Underneath that section it says:

> Stay current with announcements about Visual Studio. To see the announcements please enable dynamic content.

My question is simple: Where do I go to enable "dynamic content"?

There's also a section entitled Product Videos. Underneath it is the following message:

> We have a lot of great content to show you, but we need your permission to keep it updated.

Is this also enabled if you enable "dynamic content"? Or is there another setting I need to enable?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2013, to enable the dynamic content that is displayed on the Start Page, do the following:

1. Tools -> Options
2. Under the Environment node, select "Startup"
3. Check the box to "Download content every:" and select your interval.
4. Click OK

Your content should immediately start to populate.

Comment: Thank you, this was bugging me as well. I tweeted at MS VS team, and got no response. Should've thought of posting on SO, thanks Matthew for asking!

Comment: I agree, why not just have a button/checkbox to take you to setting, or just enable there?

Comment: This is such a usability fail. The option in tools isn't even called dynamic content!!! Nice answer though thanks @Brit Mansell

Comment: Thought I was having a corporate proxy issue and spent half a day trying to resolve this. Thanks!